# ¿Como añadir timeout similar al que está en app/webconfig a una clase, para generar una dll para asp.net (C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, timeout, app.config

Estimados, tengo una gran duda, resulta que tengo una aplicación de escritorio en C#, que se comunica con una aplicación web, en este caso con un webservice.

Desde la aplicación escritorio tengo la siguiente funcionalidad cuando presiono el boton, se comunica con el webservice:

```
public void llamarWebService(Correo,Usuario, Password)
    {

        try
        {
            ServicioWebClienteLeeXMLCorreo.ServicioWebLecturaInsercionXMLCorreoSoapClient servicio = new ServicioWebClienteLeeXMLCorreo.ServicioWebLecturaInsercionXMLCorreoSoapClient();

            var source = new BindingSource();

            var list = servicio.ObtieneXMLadjunto(Correo,Usuario, Password);
            source.DataSource = list;
            DtGridViewXMLS.DataSource = source;
            DtGridViewXMLS.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Dato 1";
            DtGridViewXMLS.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Dato 2";
            DtGridViewXMLS.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Dato 3";

            if (list.Count() > 0)
            {
                lbMensaje.Text = "Datos Econtrados";
            }
            else
            {
                lbMensaje.Text = "No se ha podido encontrar Datos";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido u error: " + error.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Además, en la aplicación de escritorio, tengo configurado el timeout, ya que sin eso, me da error de tiempo de espera cuando son muchos datos. De esta forma lo tengo en la app.config:

```
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ServicioWebLecturaInsercionXMLCorreoSoap" closeTimeout="00:05:00"
                openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="999999999"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Hasta ahí todo funciona bien, pero lo que deseo ahora, es transformar lo que tengo de la llamada de cliente al webservice a una dll con la configuración del timeout, ya que para crear la dll, no incluye no tiene el app/web.config, donde yo le daba los Timeout.
En este caso,¿como tendría que hacerlo, en que parte le daría el timeout?En alguna parte tendría que hacerlo con código C#,pero que colocaría, donde y como llamarlo o asociarlo.

Saludos cordiales, espero su respuesta.

Comment: Si entendí bien, ¿quieres "configurarle" el timeout al webservices que estés consumiendo?, puedes mirar esta [respuesta _en inglés_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/711360/4092887) o prueba investigando _si aún no lo has hecho_ de esta forma: `c# set timeout web service call`

Comment: Lo que esta en  <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>....., eso es desde la aplicación cliente, que llama al webservice. Pero como esa misma aplicación cliente, la quiero transformar en una dll, no podré incorporar esa linea de codigo, ya que está en el app.config, y en la generación de la dll, no contiene app.config. Deseo colocar la misma configuración timeout que estaba en bindings, en alguna parte del cliente, para que siga funcionando, pero no se como y donde ponerlo

Answer (score 1):

Si no entiendo mal, tienes una librería de clases (dll) que es la que hace la llamada al servicio WCF. A esta librería la llamas desde una consola.

De hecho, la configuración de `binding` que tienes en el archivo de configuración la puedes reproducir "manualmente" en el código de la librería de clases más o menos de esta forma (en este caso lo he hecho con un sólo parámetro pero por supuesto puedes incluir más):

```
    public void BasicHttpBinding CreateBasicHttpBinding(int receiveTimeOut)
    {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.AllowCookies = false;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, receiveTimeOut, 0);
        binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        binding.MaxBufferSize = 65536;
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 534288;
        binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 8192;
        return binding;
    }
```

Tu siguiente problema es reproducir la estructura de la etiqueta `binding` en el `app.config` de tu consola. La forma más sencilla es simplemente ir definiendo los diferentes parámetros en el `app.config`, es decir, yo le añadiría un valor entero de nombre `ReceiveTimeOut` por ejemplo.

Para recoger el parámetro del app.config de tu consola puedes utilizar este código:

```
int receiveTimeOut = Properties.Settings.Default.ReceiveTimeOut;
```

Una vez que lo hayas leído en la consola, sólo te queda mandarlo a la DLL con el método `CreateBasicHttpBinding` anterior al iniciar la clase.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder @Jose Antonio Bautista. Entendiste bien que la librería de clases (dll) que es la que hace la llamada al servicio WCF, con la diferencia que la llamo desde otra aplicación y no de consola para probarla(en este caso puede ser desde .net o foxpro). Mi consulta, y disculpa por la ignorancia, según el ejemplo que expuse en mi pregunta, como utilizaría el CreateBasicHttpBinding, o lo llamaría, en donde lo declararía y lo asociaría la función que se encarga de llamar al webservice(llamarWebService) la que es parte de la dll.??

Comment: No lo leo desde consola, sino de otra aplicación de prueba. Con el objetivo de ser utilizado para otro lenguaje de programación si es que deseo leerlo.

Comment: Alguien tiene alguna idea de lo que planteo??

Comment: He editado la pregunta

Comment: parece que aqui está la solución:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6d6b8efe-b8a3-4a9f-836a-3f0bb184710d/calling-a-web-service-from-a-c-dll-newbie-here?forum=wcf

lo voy a probar